# generate a password with minimum 2 numbers, 2 CAPS, 1 symbol, x lower alpha and max length of 16

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, password, random

I tried `pwgen` and `makepasswd` to generate a password...
but these are not enough to generate with exact count of literals and numbers...

```
pwgen -c -n -y -B  12 1
```

This is not working as expected as I cannot define min numbers count...
I want to define min and max chars allowed in each type of literals...
does `crunch` have this feature?
is there any other tool you suggest for this?
shell scripts are most welcome... (with regex)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run it until it works (in a newer version of bash that supports the `=~` for regex matching):

```
unset pass; 
until [[ \
        $pass =~ [0-9].*[0-9] && 
        $pass =~ [A-Z].*[A-Z] && 
        $pass =~ [^A-Za-z0-9] \
      ]]; do 
    pass=$(LC_ALL=C pwgen -c -n -y -B  12 1) 
done
```

For example:

```
$ unset pass; until [[ $pass =~ [0-9].*[0-9] && $pass =~ [A-Z].*[A-Z] && $pass =~ [^A-Za-z0-9] ]]; do pass=$(LC_ALL=C pwgen -c -n -y -B  12 1); done; echo $pass
AhP4eej3bie#
```

Note that I am defining "symbol" as "not a letter and not a number". You can choose something more restrictive if you like.

If your shell doesn't support regex matching, try:

```
$ perl -le 'until ($pass =~ /\d.*\d/ && $pass =~ /[A-Z].*[A-Z]/ && $pass =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9]/){chomp($pass=`LC_ALL=C pwgen -c -n -y -B  12 1`)}; print "$pass"'
iep7EJ-o9ahf
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have GNU grep with Perl mode installed, this can generate a password as per constraints.

```
$ < /dev/urandom \
   tr -cd '[:alnum:][:punct:]' | fold -w 12 |
   grep -Pm1 '(?=.*[[:upper:]].*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]].*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]])'

A09B?~WR~$#J
```